# Send button website

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail, send

I've made a contact form on my website with PHP and HTML. But it doesn't work. If I press the `send` button, it should me send an email with the name, email, title, message, date and time. But it doesn't send me a email. Please help me...

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="wmfg_text" name="name" id="text_id" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>email*</label>
        <input type="text" class="wmfg_text" name="eamil" id="text_id" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>title*</label>
        <input type="text" class="wmfg_text" name="title" id="text_id" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>message*</label>
        <textarea class="wmfg_textarea" name="message" id="textarea_id"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" class="wmfg_btn" name="submit" id="submit_id" value="send" />
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$title= $_POST['title']; 
$message= $_POST['message']; 
$date= date("d.m.Y"); 
$time= date("H:i:s"); 
$email_to = "myname@gmail.com"; 
$mailtext = " 
-- New message -- 
Name: $name 
Email: $email 
title: $title
date: $date
time: $time
message: $message"; 

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    mail($mailtext);
}
```

Comment: did you ever have a look at the mail() function?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer Instead of trying out phps own mail function.

Comment: The first thing to do when you have an issue _always_ is to take a look at the documentation. here that means: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You need to change   ` if(isset($_POST['send']))`  to  ` if(isset($_POST['submit']))` as   `send` is your value of submit button.

Comment: Now, I change the mail($mailtext) to mail($email_to,"My subject",$mailtext). But it doesn't work. if(isset($_POST['send'])) I changed to if($_POST['submit']))

Answer (score 0):

Your `mail()` syntax is incorrect.

Use this `mail($email_to,"My subject",$mailtext);`

**Syntax**: `mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);` Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp).

You could also use **feature rich email classes** like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need anything fancy, just use the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$title= $_POST['title']; 
$message= $_POST['message']; 
$date= date("d.m.Y"); 
$time= date("H:i:s"); 
$email_to = "myname@gmail.com"; 
$mailtext = " 
-- New message -- \r\n
Name: {$name}\r\n 
Email: {$email}\r\n 
title: {$title}\r\n
date: {$date}\r\n
time: {$time}\r\n
message: {$message}\r\n"; 

if($_POST['submit']))
{
    mail($to,$subject,$mailtext)
}
```